# Unable to save data to Core Data second related entity

Tags: core-data, xcode4.5, magicalrecord

I have an iPad app, built with XCode 4.5, Storyboard, Core Data (using MagicalRecord) and iOS 6.  I have two Entities, each with multiple attributes.  The first entity has a one to many relationship with the second entity.

In the MagicalRecord docs, I don't see how to persist the data to the second entity; I read somewhere that Core Data generates it's own key and indexes.  I know from past use of SQLite that I would need to set the key from the first entity to be able to access the second entity.

**[UPDATED]** Here is the modified code but it doesn't work either.  I have previously selected a row in didSelectRowAtIndexedPath in another class.  I assume that set the localContext.  Any ideas why this is not working?

```
- (IBAction)saveAppointment:(UIButton *)sender {

    AppointmentInfo *newAppointment = [AppointmentInfo MR_createInContext:localContext];  //  create the entity

    newAppointment.aStartTime = selectedStartDate;
    newAppointment.aEndTime= selectedEndDate;

    [localContext MR_saveNestedContexts];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create your Entity in the proper (ie. localContext) context:

```
[AppointmentInfo MR_createInContext:localContext];
```

Comment: This is what I tried, and it doesn't work either... no build errors, just doesn't save the data.

    NSManagedObjectContext *localContext = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_contextForCurrentThread];

    AppointmentInfo *newAppointment = [AppointmentInfo MR_createInContext:localContext];  //  create the entity

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem... seems that I had the store setup incorrectly... I removed the parent pointer from AppointmentInfo and added the "class" information.  Works like a champ now... thank you for your time, tho'.